# Iterate data in table rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datatable

I have the data table in which I have to show the info in the row of the table.  In the userDetails, it contains information about the user. What my problem is, when I am iterating tableData, I am getting all the infos fetched in all the rows, instead of fetching 1 data in 1 row.
Below is the response structure:

```
[
    {
        "info": "Ron",
        "address": "NY",
        "id": "2113",
        "date": "2015-10-10",
    },
    {
        "info": "Mark",
        "address": "mt@ibm.com",
        "id": "3323",
        "date": "2019-01-10",
    },
]
const tableData = (
    <>
    <div>User Info </div>
      {userDetails.map((data) => (
        <>   
          <div>
            {data.info}
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

there are 2 rows in the table, I want info as **"Ron"** in the first row, **"Mark"** in the second row. What I am getting while iterating tableData is Ron, Mark in 1st row and again Ron, Mark in 2nd row. I am pretty sure that I am iterating the tableData in a wrong way, but couldn't find the right approach. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like? Just remember to put everything you want repeated for each row into the map() callback.

Comment: I am getting all the response in all the rows, rather I want 1 response to be fetched in each row

Comment: Please, include how do you fetch responses - it sounds very important to the question.

Comment: there is a column in a table "Info". I am iterating my tableData(snippet added in the question) in the info table. I am getting "Ron" & "Mark"(check the response attached in the row) both fetched in all the rows, rather I want "Ron" in the 1st row & "Mark" in the second row to be fetched

Comment: @Singh You need to show us the component you are using. There is no enough information to debug.

Answer (score 0):

@Singh - You seem to be doing it correct. My only suggestion is to use a `table` tag, if you are looking for row & column based layout.

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>User Info</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {userDetails.map((userDetail) => (
             return (<tr>
               <td> {userDetail.info} </td>
             </tr>);
        )}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The tag `<tr>` will be the repetitive item returned inside the `map` function.